# Why does not work group middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the following middleware in routing Laravel:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::resource('Order', 'OrderController');
});
```

When I try to call this path in URL:

```
http://localhost/web/order
```

I get an error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> in RouteCollection.php line 161 at
>   RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821 at
>   Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691 at
>   Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675 at
>   Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246 at
>   Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   52 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 at
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   32 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   102 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132 at
>   Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line
>   99 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Route::group();`, as its name stands, is for grouping routes that shares something in common.

`'middleware' => 'web'` will make all the routes inside share the same group of middleware or share the same middleware. Look at `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

The middleware will not affect your route URL but how the route is treated in your app.

`'prefix' => 'web'` will make all your routes share the same path. Which looks more to what you need.

The right code will be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::resource('Order', 'OrderController');
});
```

The URL to access this route will be:

`/web/order`

To have both, prefix `web` and middleware `auth` with guard `api` `auth:api`, the code would be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'web', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::resource('Order', 'OrderController');
});
```

Comment: How I can add Auth here? Something like as: `"middleware" => "auth:api" `in `Route::group`

Comment: Also I tried this: `Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::resource('Order', 'OrderController');
});
`

Comment: `auth` is the middleware for authentication, `api` is for the guard configuration defined in `config/auth.php`. Adding `'middleware' => ['auth:api']` will do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `'prefix' => 'web'` instead of `'middleware' => 'web'` if you are looking for a url like in your post. By default, Laravel 5.2 wraps all routes in the 'web' middleware, don't have to declare it again.

I can't clearly explain what middleware is other than it guards certain routes based on rules in place.
[Laravel documentation on route prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Comment: But if I need to add middleware with auth?

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'web', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'api']], function ()
{}